# char conversion in ternary operator in Java, prints int value instead of char value

Tags: java, casting, conditional-operator, primitive, primitive-types

In Java, you can cast `char` to `int` and vice-versa, using the char value or the ASCII value. If you cast an int variable to a char, you get the corresponding character. So, the following snippet will print 'a':

```
int x = 97;
System.out.println( (char)x ); // 'a'
```

But when I do this:

```
char ch = 'a', ch2 = 97, ch3 = 'b';
System.out.println( ( (ch+=1) > ch2 ) ? (char)ch2 : (int)ch3 );
```

the compiler prints out the int value 97, not 'a', even though the ternary operator return value on the 'true side' is (char)ch2. So I expected 'a' instead of 97. Why does it print 97 instead of 'a'?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that in:

```
System.out.println(((ch += 1) > ch2) ? (char) ch2 : (int) ch3);
```

because you have `(int) ch3` the compiler assumes that the returning type of the ternary operator will be an `int`.

Check the **highlighted** part of the rule from JLS [15.25. Conditional Operator ? :](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25)

> The type of a conditional expression is determined as follows:
>
> - If the second and third operands have the same type (which may be the null type), then that is the type of the conditional expression.
> - If one of the second and third operands is of primitive type T, and the type of the other is the result of applying boxing conversion
>   (§5.1.7) to T, then the type of the conditional expression is T.
> - If one of the second and third operands is of the null type and the type of the other is a reference type, then the type of the
>   conditional expression is that reference type.
> - Otherwise, if the second and third operands have types that are convertible (§5.1.8) to numeric types, then there are several cases:
>
>   - If one of the operands is of type byte or Byte and the other is of type short or Short, then the type of the conditional expression is
>     short.
>   - If one of the operands is of type T where T is byte, short, or char, and the other operand is a constant expression (§15.28) of type
>     int whose value is representable in type T, then the type of the
>     conditional expression is T.
>   - If one of the operands is of type T, where T is Byte, Short, or Character, and the other operand is a constant expression (§15.28) of
>     type int whose value is representable in the type U which is the
>     result of applying unboxing conversion to T, then the type of the
>     conditional expression is U.
>   - **Otherwise, binary numeric promotion (§5.6.2) is applied to the operand types, and the type of the conditional expression is the
>     promoted type of the second and third operands.**
>
>     Note that binary numeric promotion performs value set conversion
>     (§5.1.13) and may perform unboxing conversion (§5.1.8).
> - Otherwise, the second and third operands are of types S1 and S2 respectively. Let T1 be the type that results from applying boxing
>   conversion to S1, and let T2 be the type that results from applying
>   boxing conversion to S2.

If you do

```
System.out.println(((ch += 1) > ch2 ) ? (char) ch2 : (char) ch3);
```

it will print

```
'a'
```

Alternatively, you can apply brute-force i.e. cast the final result into `char` as shown below:

```
System.out.println((char) (((ch += 1) > ch2 ) ? (char) ch2 : (int) ch3));
```

it will also print

```
 'a'
```