# Character.isDigit is returning different results in conditional operator

Tags: java, digits

Code 1 returns 1.

Code 2 returns 49.

Shouldn't they return the same result?

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String code = "1";
        StringBuilder digitSB = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i = 0; i < code.length(); i++){
            char chr = code.charAt(i);
            //Code 1
            if(Character.isDigit(chr)){
                digitSB.append(chr);
            }
            else{
                digitSB.append(Character.getNumericValue(chr));
            }
            System.out.println("Code 1 result: " + digitSB);
            //Code 2
            digitSB = new StringBuilder();
            digitSB.append(Character.isDigit(chr) ? chr : Character.getNumericValue(chr));
            System.out.println("Code 2 result: " + digitSB);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that 49 is the ASCII code of 1.

**Edit:** It's as @matt said in the comments. When you use the ternary operator, both sides of the ":" are considered the same type. Since getNumericValue assumes it's an int, both sides are an int. The condition is true, so it takes the left side, which is chr, but considers it an int.

Comment: This is a bit tricky. I think, because you're using the ternary operator, both clauses of your statement are being treated as `int` there is a dup for this lying around that will be more clear.

Comment: [Also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66615473/char-conversion-in-ternary-operator-in-java-prints-int-value-instead-of-char-va) related.

Comment: *digitSB.append(Character.getNumericValue(chr));* In what way would it be useful to append a binary 1 (or other number) to a ```String``` /```StringBuilder``` ?

Comment: @g00se It converts it to a string. `StringBuilder` has a method specifically for adding Integers. Why is it crazy for somebody to use it?

Comment: @matt Thank you. I don't know how I managed to miss the existence of that method in all these years ;)

Comment: @matt you have the right answer. They're treated as int as you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return type treated as int in case of ternary operator. Use like this

```
Character.isDigit(chr) ? chr : ""+ Character.getNumericValue(chr);
```

or

```
Character.isDigit(chr) ? ""+chr :  Character.getNumericValue(chr);
```